# VSCode can´t open any external file

Tags: 22.04

A few days ago, my VS Code on Ubuntu 22.04 just stopped opening any external files, network, and USB devices.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Looks like it can't find mounting place on the OS.

###### Normal OS View

[image: Normal OS View]

###### VS Code View

[image: VS Code View]